# How to avoid problem with folder name in batch-file?

Tags: batch-file

I'm trying to add security in batch file. This is working with all folders, except the first one : 5 - Models. It just does nothing.
[Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/M3ZGn.png)

But, if I have a folder before, like 1, the security on the folder 1 is executed, but stop at 5 - Models.
[Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dyAtk.png)

This is the code I'm trying. This code is working elsewhere :

```
@echo off
FOR /D /r %%G in ("*") DO (
    IF NOT '%%~nxG' == 'Clients' (
        icacls "%%G" /deny Usine:D
        icacls "%%G" /deny Usine1:D
        icacls "%%G" /deny Usine2:D
        icacls "%%G" /deny Usine3:D
        icacls "%%G" /deny Usine4:D
        icacls "%%G" /deny Usine5:D
        icacls "%%G" /deny Usine6:D
        icacls "%%G" /deny Usine7:D
        icacls "%%G" /deny Usine8:D
        icacls "%%G" /deny Usine9:D
        icacls "%%G" /deny Usine10:D
    )
)
pause
```

I've also tried without single quote, and it's not working.

I've remove the `@echo off` to see the result :

```
(IF NOT '5 - Models' == 'Clients' (
 icacls "P:\Réservoirs\5 - Models" /deny Usine:D
 icacls "P:\Réservoirs\5 - Models" /deny Usine1:D
 icacls "P:\Réservoirs\5 - Models" /deny Usine2:D
 icacls "P:\Réservoirs\5 - Models" /deny Usine3:D
 icacls "P:\Réservoirs\5 - Models" /deny Usine4:D
 icacls "P:\Réservoirs\5 - Models" /deny Usine5:D
 icacls "P:\Réservoirs\5 - Models" /deny Usine6:D
 icacls "P:\Réservoirs\5 - Models" /deny Usine7:D
 icacls "P:\Réservoirs\5 - Models" /deny Usine8:D
 icacls "P:\Réservoirs\5 - Models" /deny Usine9:D
 icacls "P:\Réservoirs\5 - Models" /deny Usine10:D
) )
```

What can be the problem and how can I solve it ?

Comment: Bash has nothing to do with Windows batch scripts. I'm completely sure that Bash is not the command interpreter which executes this script. Do you mean Cmd.exe? And single quotes are not at all special to Cmd.exe. You probably want `If Not "%%~nxG" == "Clients"`.

Comment: I'd suggest you make that case insensitive too, `If /I Not "%%~nxG"=="Clients" (`.

Comment: @AlexP This is a .bat file, isn't it a batch ?

Comment: This is not working with double quotes..

Comment: @CodeVeteran: The question was originally tagged Bash, and began: "I'm trying to add security in **bash**". A kind soul edited it and corrected the tags. Batch files and Bash scripts are different beasts. (And you may want to read up of `for /?`, because `for /d` and `for /r` have different rules.)

Comment: `IF /I NOT "%%~nxG" == "Clients" (`

Comment: I've already suggested that @CodeVeteran, and the OP suggested it didn't work. I'd suggest possibly `Echo "%%~nxG"|Find /I "Clients">NUL||(`, which will check to see if the string `Clients` is anywhere in the directory name, instead of checking for a case insenstitive whole string match. _(This would ensure that any unseen trailing space character in the `Clients` directory is catered for)_. Other than that their error seems more than likely incorrectly reported.